# CodeMR Analyzer in Eclipse does not work with C/C++ Code

Tags: c++, eclipse

I want to use CodeMR in Eclipse for analysing C/C++ code. I installed CodeMR via the marketplace. It works well for Java applications but when I go to "CodeMR" -> "Extract Model" I get to following error:

> No suitable extractor found for selected files, extension list: [cpp,
> h]

I installed the C/C++ Development Tooling for Eclipse. How can I solve this error?

Comment: The CodeMR component containing the extractor for C/C++ might not be installed since you installed it before you installed the _C/C++ Development Tooling for Eclipse_. Does reinstalling or uninstall+install of CodeMR work?

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. This solved my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CodeMR component containing the extractor for C/C++ might not be installed since you installed it before you installed the *C/C++ Development Tooling for Eclipse*.

As a solution, reinstall CodeMR or **uninstall+install CodeMR** while *C/C++ Development Tooling for Eclipse* is installed.