# eclipse does not recognize variable initialized with {} in c++ constructor

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to load an existing pool of c++17 sources into an eclipse (2023.03) project. The style of coding is like the following:

```
#include <string>

class X {
    std::string name;
public:
    X(const std::string &n) : name{n} {}
};
```

It is compilable with gcc with no warnings. However, eclipse complains about 'name' in the initializer list: *Symbol 'name' could not be resolved".

I tried to add -std=c++17 to every entry with cdt compiler which i could find but it does not help:

- c/c++->general->preprocessors->providers
- c/c++->build->discovery.

The issue does not go away. The only way it works if '{n}' are replaced '(n)'. But it means that a lot of code has to change.

What am I missing?

Comment: Report the issue at their official site? as this is clearly an eclipse issue.

Comment: Also see [How to enable C++11/C++0x support in Eclipse CDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/how-to-enable-c11-c0x-support-in-eclipse-cdt)

Comment: @Jason I've seen similar suggestions, most of them do not apply. For some reason, there is no 'C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings' tab at all.

Comment: Interesting. I have a fully-custom build and not interested in make files. So, I checked off 'generate makefiles automatically'. This caused disappearance of the 'tool setting' tab in settings :-(. I tried to add the std qual in this mode. However, it still did not help.

Comment: *there is no 'C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings' tab at all.* Is this a makefile project? If so you probably want to head to C/C++ General-> PreProcessor Include Paths, Macros, etc... -> Providers tab -> Built-in compiler settings -> and add `-std=c++17` to the *Command to get compiler specs:* field.

Comment: @user4581301 i did that (in the question). did not work.

Comment: Is this relevant?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66634420/codemr-analyzer-in-eclipse-does-not-work-with-c-c-code/66635804#66635804

Comment: @Red.Wave  no, it is not relevant.